# asp.net web API + angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

День добрый, друзья.
Я новичок в AngularJs.
Даже не знаю как описать проблему, запускаю index.html и вижу это вот
 [image: результат]

ссылка на проект:
https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ak_moPQxbA1SgXvqi_eLnNICYrzi

Если кто может подсказать мне, что я делаю не так, буду бесконечно признателен.

Comment: стоит посмотреть ошибки в консоли браузера. Скорее всего ты открываешь просто шаблон, а не страницу с angular

Comment: Да, Вы правы, ошибки есть.
http://i84.fastpic.ru/big/2016/1111/4c/9cf5204faeb2cb914e0b09790472dc4c.png

Comment: Тогда после исправления ошибок - все будет нормально

Comment: Вы не подскажите, что конкретно нужно исправить?
http://plnkr.co/edit/kYNWqecPBPiTCZYtSWJD?p=preview

Comment: конкретно в планкере для бутстрапа нужен jQuery, об этом он и пишет одинку. Ну и так же он не может найти скрипты которые внизу подключены, потому что нужно поправить пути. Что значит `<script src="application/"></script>` вообще непонятно